# rails request.headers cannot get values

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to get some values from the headers in my rails app. If I iterate over request.headers like

```
request.headers.each do |k,v|
```

I get all the things I need (and much more ;-) ):

```
HTTPS: on
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip, deflate
givenName: MemyselfandI
mail: noone@nowhere.org
```

However I can only access HTTP-headers like "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING" etc. I cannot access e.g. mail:

```
request.headers['mail']
```

is nil.

Is there anyway to get the values of "mail" and "givenName" etc?

Thanks in advance,
Sven

Comment: Why are you expecting to get `mail` header? It isn't standart HTTP header, are you sure it was sent and it wasn't cut by intermidiate proxy or something like it? Moreover Rails adds prefix `HTTP_` to headers from the request, for example `ACCEPT_ENCODING` is a standard header, but it's available only with prefix `HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING`. Are you sure  there is no header `HTTP_mail` in request headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I found the solution:

```
request.headers.env['key'] = value
```

So, to get the value of mail you have to

```
request.headers.env['mail']
```

All the best,
Sven